# Natural quantum states with energy uncertainty

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

If I have a quantum system but I let it interact with the environment, I expect it to be in a Gibbs state $\frac{1}{Z(\beta)}e^{-\beta H}$. This means I'm in a mixed state, where the pure states in that mixture are all energy eigenstates of $H$. This leaves room for coherent superpositions over any observables that have energy degeneracies, e.g., if energy is invariant for the position of some particle, there could be some superposition of positions. I don't have to do anything to maintain that superposition, either: even with normal interactions with the environment, I expect that superposition to remain coherent. However, there is no superposition over energy levels: every pure state in the mixture has a single energy.

Is there any way to get a similar superposition of energy levels in a quantum system, without working to maintain coherence (e.g., without microkelvin temperatures, etc.)? The derivation of the Gibbs state seems to imply that interaction with a heat bath will, over time, effectively measure the energy of the system. Is there some other way to interact with a heat bath where we end up "measuring" some other observable, such that the eigenstates are in a superposition of energy levels?

Comment: Why do you think that Gibbs states contain coherent superpositions within energy eigenspaces? The claim is false - that sector of the state is completely mixed, which is as far as you can get from coherence.

Comment: Two main reasons:
1) If there is no superposition in any eigenspace, then there is no way to bootstrap any quantum phenomenon, i.e., if an experimentalist creates a qubit in a superposition state where the two states differ in some conserved quantity, then that conserved quantity must have come from the environment, entangling the qubit with the environment to some degree. If the environment is in a completely mixed state (w.r.t. that conserved quantity), this will decohere the qubit.

Comment: 2) Heisenberg uncertainty: If position/momentum are degenerate in that eigenspace, at least one of the two must be in superposition

Also: A completely mixed state is somewhat ambiguous since a completely uniform mixture of pure states from any orthonormal basis will give the same completely mixed states. So if you tell me that "really" the mixed state is a mixture over bases $B_1$ (i.e, it's pure states from $B_1$ entangled with some external system), then I can choose a basis $B_2$ where each pure state is a superposition over several basis states from $B_2$.